# A DB of banks for each country

Tags: data-request, finance, csv, companies

I'm looking for a **free** database of banks (preferably with their web sites, phone numbers, etc) for each country in a convenient format, not html.  Is there any?

Comment: You'd be foolish to exclude a format just because it's more annoying to work with; HTML may be a pain to parse, but if it's a complete record, I'd rather have that then try to merge a table w/ phone numbers to a table w/ web addresses.

Answer (score 3):

The FDIC has a data download of all finanically insured banks and their branch offices in the US. The data does not have though website and phone number. It does have name, address, institution type, deposits.

https://www2.fdic.gov/IDASP/warp_download_all.asp

The FDIC dataset on Data.gov has some additional fields, including website (but not phone):

http://catalog.data.gov/dataset/fdic-institution-directory-id-insured-insitution-download-file/resource/df80f510-8c30-421d-8f83-f90f0ebf887b

Comment: in **all the countries**

Comment: I don't need for the US, I need for all the countries.

Comment: @alexander - I checked the IMF, Central Bank and other international sources but could not find (free) lists of institutions worldwide.

Comment: I've worked with the FDIC download and there are a lot of inaccuracies. Banks that were absorbed by other banks during the banking system meltdown of 2008-2010 and banks that ceased to exist are still listed in the Db.