# A list of all the banks by country

Tags: data-request, finance, bank

I'm looking for a list of all the banks and their details, or just the biggest ones, by country. Is there any?

Comment: Where have you looked so far? I would consider open street map if you just need names and locations.

Comment: Also check out https://opencorporates.com/

Comment: @Skram, how can I do that in osm? by a tag?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [A DB of banks for each country](http://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/3843/a-db-of-banks-for-each-country)

Answer (score 3):

Wikipedia has lists of all the banks in certain countries, those seem pretty accurate for the larger banks and countries with more active wikipedia communities.

For more in depth data, I think you might have to get the data for each country seperately through their financial supervision department. The United States has that data here: https://cdr.ffiec.gov/public/

A good place to start for the EU is here: http://www.efsf.europa.eu/about/links/index.htm

The Dutch association for banks has a list of members here: https://www.nvb.nl/vereniging/120/leden.html

Furthermore, companies like pwc publish reports on the banking sector, such as this one for China: http://www.pwccn.com/webmedia/doc/634442705425169010_fs_foreign_banks_china_jun2011.pdf